# How to send Form Data to Laravel controller using Javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to send the form below to Laravel controller using javascript fetch, but the form data is not been sent to the controller.

I need help, also if can be done with Ajax, show me example

Here is the HTML form

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('verify_account') }}" id="email_verification"
                            onsubmit='verify_code("email_verification")'>
   @csrf
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
        <div class="otp_input_container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center py-4 my-4">
            <input type="number" name="phone[]" id="" class="form-control py-2 mr-2 px-1 text-center otpInput" autofocus maxlength="1">
            <input type="number" name="phone[]" id="" class="form-control mx-2 py-2 px-1 text-center otpInput" maxlength="1">
            <input type="number" name="phone[]" id="" class="form-control mx-2 py-2 px-1 text-center otpInput" maxlength="1">
            <input type="number" name="phone[]" id="" class="form-control mx-2 py-2 px-1 text-center otpInput" maxlength="1">
            <input type="number" name="phone[]" id="" class="form-control mx-2 py-2 px-1 text-center otpInput" maxlength="1">
             <input type="number" name="phone[]" id="" class="form-control py-2 px-1 text-center ml-2 otpInput" maxlength="1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary py-2 px-5 mb-4 " type="submit">Verify</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Here is Javacript fetch code**

```
 function verify_code(formId) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById(formId));
            let token = document.head.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']")

            let _data = {
                form_data: formData,
                _token: token.content
            }
          
            const options = {
                method: "POST",
                body: JSON.stringify(_data),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                }
            }

            fetch(document.getElementById(formId).action, options)
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.json();
                    }
                    throw new Error('Error: ' + response.status);
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    // Handle the success response
                    console.log("succuss " + data);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle the error
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
```

Comment: Please provide your controller code.

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: You shouldn't create a new object with the form data and the csrf token. You should be passing the form data itself. You can add the token to the form data, or you can pass the token as a `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in the header.